# Should character specs be considered an off-topic question?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, subjective

I'm fairly new to SE and I've become sort of an addict to these sites. In my daily scouring of gaming.SE, I've noticed some questions regarding what the best specs/skills are to pick up for your character (WoW characters, Skyrim characters, etc.).
Some examples of these questions:

- [Example 1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18495/how-do-i-properly-spec-as-a-balance-druid)
- [Example 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4657/what-is-the-best-leveling-spec-for-a-champion-in-lotro)
- [Example 3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4087/wow-healadin-lvl-60-70-gear-spec-glyphs-and-suggestions)

I think these questions should be considered as non-constructive since defining one spec over another as "best" or "proper" is subjective and could lead to debate. Any thoughts?